# How to figure out real life examples of design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

Hi 
  I am learning design patterns from a book . How to figure out the actual production code where it is implemented .

For example  , if I am learning strategy pattern  , it might be implemented in Spring framework . But how to go and search there and see it .

Do you guys have any easy ways of finding such stuff ?

Comment: Have you read the J2EE BluePrints documentation yet?  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/blueprints/index.html.  Please read some of that and then **update** your question with specific links or references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You often don't need to see the code to have a good idea of what pattern is being implemented. What's important is how the classes interact with other objects, and that you can deduce from looking at its Methods and Properties.

For example, lots of C# and Java Libraries have classes where there is not a constructor for the class, but there is a "CreateWidget()" function which returns a new Widget dependent on some parameters you pass that function. That is an example of a "Factory" pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around.
You shouldn't code based on a design pattern. Pattern emerges in your code. It's then you make the code more general and make it based on a design pattern.
When you start repeating yourself then you should ask your self if there isn't a pattern that should fit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general Books about design patters show an actual implementation in some language (Like [Gamma's Design Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633612)).

If your looking for implementations of design patterns on a certain software its a bit harder because each implementation not always follows the exact same patter. I think one way to find them is trying to look for parts of the software that resolv esome kind of generic problem (like rendering a window is most probable that uses a composite pattern).